# What is a good software/hardware combination for biofeedback monitoring that includes GSR, GSM, HRV, and EEG?

Tags: eeg, software

i'm looking for a lab setup for psychological experiments to help people relieve stress better with various auditory and visual stimuli.

what i want is a software like brainbay that can use not just EEG, but GSR sensors, ECG or HRV sensors at the very least. that being said, it'd be nice to have audiostrobe compatibility as well. i know brainbay and even MATLAB have EEG and even camera capabilities to track eye movement. but i'm looking for something more than just EEG. even EEG and GSR would be amazing. hell, even if someone could point me to a GSR plugin and audiostrobe plugin for brainbay.

and secondly, hardware. i know the Epoc Emotiv is used in a lot of EEG-only applications, including being a standard option within brainbay. is this a good buy for at-home non-medical research? at school they have 3000\$ plus equiptment and as a student, i can't afford that kind of set up. i'm looking for a good but non-medical grade headset and GSR sensor. most headsets i see are around 200-300\$ and that's ok for me.

so, my question is, what is a good setup that you guys use? what can you suggest to me?

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions here. First, you have how to analyse multiple signals and output to various actuators without programming. Second, you seem to be asking about the quality of consumer EEG hardware. Third, you're asking about the quality of consumer GSR hardware. Your first question is too broad, but your second two are salvageable if you split them off into separate questions.

Comment: I agree with Seanny123 on this. However, I just asked http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/open-source-software-for-analyzing-electrodermal-activity . Hopefully, any of those packages may be of use to you. I do think you are asking a lot of the software package, to include many variables and I am in doubt whether it exists. It is possible that there are enough Matlab/Python plugins that you can combine. The only thing you need to do then is organizing the data in such a way that you can combine it.

Comment: BioPac is famous for having all kinds of sensors and analysis packages. With a lot of money that is your best, if not only, bet. Also have a look at MoviSens. They at least have EDA and HRV, both hard and software.