# Best sensor/wearable to measure ppg and/or gsr

Tags: measurement

So I'm doing a thesis and need to find the best sensor/wearable that has a open api so I can access the data, that measures gsr (galvanic skin response) and ppg (photoplethysmography).

I've seen a lot of bands but mostly discontinued (Microsoft band 2) and the e4 is really expensive (https://www.empatica.com/e4-wristband)

What do you recommend and why?

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Joao, a similar question was asked a while ago (see the linked question of my previous comment). Is that question helpful already?

Comment: @RobinKramer I already saw that post, but mostly they are expensive or discontinued and i was looking for new alternatives

Comment: Could you specify more clearly what some criteria are then, e.g. what is your budget? Without clear and different criteria, it would be more useful to gather all answers in the other question (and, therefore, close this one as a duplicate).

Comment: @JoaoMelo I [added an updated answer to the duplicate question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/18232/21). However, the sources provided there already seemed quite exhaustive. In case you are specifically looking for less expensive devices, perhaps try formulating this question along those lines. Possibly there are some 'make-it-yourself' solutions in the maker movement (do keep in mind you can expect doing it yourself to be quite complex). In case you do, ping me and I will reopen.