# Accuracy and precision of wearable devices to measure galvanic skin response?

Tags: measurement

How accurate and precise are wearable devices to measure galvanic skin response compared to laboratory quality equipment? [This discussion](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/16206/17770) includes some details on the accuracy of wrist-based measurement devices but not for devises that measure at palms and fingers (see response [here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/18232/17770) and [here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/16585/17770)).

Steven Jeuris [lists three wearable devices](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/18232/17770) supporting electrodes on the palms/fingers:

- [Shimmer](http://www.shimmersensing.com/products/shimmer3-wireless-gsr-sensor)
- [movisens edaMove](https://www.movisens.com/en/products/eda-sensor/)
- [Moodmetric ring](http://www.moodmetric.com/)

How accurate and precise are they compared to laboratory quality equipment, how do they compare with each other and how do they compare with wrist-based measurement devices?