# How to work with EDA data in R environment?

Tags: data

I'm looking to pull EDA data from an Empatica e4 into R. I can find packages and code that will enable this in Python and Matlab (see this [previous thread](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16017/open-source-software-for-analyzing-electrodermal-activity)) but not R. I'm much more familiar with R and if at all possible would like to be able to work in that environment.

Comment: I think this question should be added in the previous thread so if someone provides a response is added in the good list developed by Robin Kramer. Unfortunately I think I've never seen anything in R for this purpose https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_date.html